# How to put book information from amazon into a table form?

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I have an amazon [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0971576610), i.e.,
[image]

I'm able to extract `Product details` from the HTML with `soup.select("#detailBullets_feature_div .a-unordered-list:first-child")`, i.e.,

```
<ul class="a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-vertical a-spacing-none detail-bullet-list">
<li><span class="a-list-item"> <span class="a-text-bold">Publisher : </span> <span>Matrix Editions (January 1, 2007)</span> </span></li>
<li><span class="a-list-item"> <span class="a-text-bold">Language : </span> <span>English</span> </span></li>
<li><span class="a-list-item"> <span class="a-text-bold">Hardcover : </span> <span>640 pages</span> </span></li>
<li><span class="a-list-item"> <span class="a-text-bold">ISBN-10 : </span> <span>0971576610</span> </span></li>
<li><span class="a-list-item"> <span class="a-text-bold">ISBN-13 : </span> <span>978-0971576612</span> </span></li>
<li><span class="a-list-item"> <span class="a-text-bold">Item Weight : </span> <span>2.3 pounds</span> </span></li>
</ul>
```

Could you explain how to put above data in a tabular form? My expected result is
[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

link = 'https://www.amazon.com/Functional-Analysis-Dzung-Ha/dp/0971576610'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
soup.select("#detailBullets_feature_div .a-unordered-list:first-child")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a dictionary by using the `span.a-text-bold`s for keys and the rest of the texts in each `span.a-list-item` as values (like in the function defined below), and that dictionary can be used to form a row in a DataFrame.

```py
def get_product_details(prod_soup):
    rkSel = 'span.a-list-item>span.a-text-bold:first-child'
    rkSel = f'div#detailBullets_feature_div {rkSel}'

    pDets = {}
    for r in prod_soup.select(rkSel):
        k = r.get_text(' ', strip=True) 
        v = r.parent.get_text(' ', strip=True).replace(k,'',1).strip() 
        if 'Rank' in k and v[:1]=='#': v = ' • #'.join(v.split(' #'))

        pDets[k.split('\n')[0].strip(':')] = v
    return pDets
```

---

For your `link`, `get_product_details(soup)` should return

> ```py
> {'Publisher': 'Matrix Editions (January 1, 2007)',
>  'Language': 'English',
>  'Hardcover': '640 pages',
>  'ISBN-10': '0971576610',
>  'ISBN-13': '978-0971576612',
>  'Item Weight': '2.3 pounds',
>  'Best Sellers Rank': '#7,261,544 in Books ( See Top 100 in Books )',
>  'Customer Reviews': '5.0 out of 5 stars 2 ratings'}
> ```

and `pd.DataFrame([get_product_details(soup)])` should return [image: opdf1]

---

You could loop through multiple links to fill multiple rows:

```py
urls_list = [
    'https://www.amazon.com/Atomic-Habits-Proven-Build-Break/dp/0735211299',
    'https://www.amazon.com/Functional-Analysis-Dzung-Ha/dp/0971576610',
    'https://www.amazon.com/Daisy-Jones-Taylor-Jenkins-Reid/dp/1524798649',
    'https://www.amazon.com/Body-Keeps-Score-Healing-Trauma/dp/0143127748',
    'https://www.amazon.com/History-Uncertain-Future-Handwriting/dp/1620402157'
]
```

```py
books_list = []
for url in urls_list:
    soup = linkToSoup_scrapingAnt(url)
    # books_list.append(get_product_details(soup)) ## no extra columns

    kList, sList = ['Title','Author'], ['span#productTitle','span.author']
    book_info = { k: t.get_text(' ', strip=True) if t else None for k,t 
                  in zip(kList, [soup.select_one(s) for s in sList])    }
    books_list.append({**book_info, **get_product_details(soup)})
```

[image: opdfmr]

---

---

**Note:** If you want only the section covered in the HTML snippet in your question (i.e., without the `Best Sellers Rank` and `Customer Reviews` keys/columns), you can define `rkSel` as

```py
    rkSel = 'ul:first-of-type span.a-list-item>span.a-text-bold:first-child'
    rkSel = f'h2+div#detailBullets_feature_div {rkSel}'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! It is more than what I asked for :v